# open a url tab that loops an argument

Tags: python

I am trying to count a phone number up to 100 an have it change the url and count for me. How can i turn the url into a varibale and change it for me? is this even possible?

Objective: enter a phone number 
add the phone number at the end of the url and have it count up from that phone number in the url .

Example: a friend wrote down her number but the last two numbers were ripped off. I want to enter her number and have it search up to 00-99 on advanced phone book to find her full number. I want the browser to update for me and not have to type and count up to 99 to find her full number//

```
import webbrowser
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

#what number you are searching
number = input('enter number: ')

#browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
webbrowser.open('https://www.advancedbackgroundchecks.com/'+ (number))

#counting
count = 0
while count <= 100:
        print(str(number) + str(count).zfill(2))
        count = count + 1
```

Comment: You miss `+` after the string and before the number

Comment: @Infinity ok ty i fixed but how do i have it count

Comment: + count too >? ?????

Comment: can you explain what you want with an example? it's kinda ambiguous !

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi Example: a friend wrote down her number but the last two numbers were ripped off. I want to enter her number and have it search up to 00-99 on advanced phone book to find her full number. I want the browser to update for me and not have to type and count up to 99 to find her full number// does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a formattable url, like :

```
number = input('enter number: ')
url = f'https://www.advancedbackgroundchecks.com/{number}'+'{}'
```

now you can add count to the base number :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
for count in range(100):
    webbrowser.open(url.format('{0:02d}'.format(count)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .format(count) and append it to the link, putting a zero before numbers under 10 as you want it from 00 to 99

```
import webbrowser
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

#what number you are searching
number = input('enter number: ')

#browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.advancedbackgroundchecks.com/'+str(number)+'{}'
# Also, its better if you just loop through a range rather then keep a variable count, unless you are going to use it later.
for i in range(100):
    x = i
    if i < 10:
        x = '0'+str(i)
    webbrowser.open(url.format(str(x)))
```

Comment: it won't work ! you are changing the type of `i` from `int` to `str` in the for loop !

Comment: ,,,, which happens anyway when we reach the url.

Comment: `i` should be incremented from 0 to 99 by 1 :/ you are changing the type of `i` at the first iteration =|

Comment: ive added another variable to fix it, also unfortunately your answer will not work. You do not include 00, 01, 02 etc.

Comment: try my answer, then you'll upvote it because of `'{0:02d}'.format(count)`

Comment: Oh i see, sorry i missed that.

Comment: now i'll upvote yours, btw don't try to make your code like a spaghetti code.